# Q.js progress handler doesn't seem to be firing

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, promise, q

I'm currently using Q.js for promises, since they implement progress handlers. However, it doesn't seem like they're firing. What am I doing wrong? It seems pretty basic, so I must be missing something. (The example below is written in coffeescript)

```
Q = require('q')
squares = (list) ->
  deferred = Q.defer()
  result = list.map (e) ->
    r = e * e
    deferred.notify(r)
    return r
  deferred.resolve(result)
  return deferred.promise

squares([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
  .then((result) ->
    console.log result
  ).progress((e) ->
    console.log e
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

`squares` is executed synchronously, thus `deferred.notify` and `deferred.resolve` are invoked before any listeners are bound. Seems like already fulfilled promises still invokes the `fulfilled` callbacks but not any `progress` callbacks. You could wrap part of the code with `setTimeout` like this:

```
Q = require('q')

squares = (list) ->
  deferred = Q.defer()
  setTimeout (->
    result = list.map (e) ->
      r = e * e
      deferred.notify(r)
      return r
    deferred.resolve(result)
    ), 0
  return deferred.promise

squares([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
  .progress((e) ->
    console.log e
  ).then((result) ->
    console.log result
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

This discussion thread on github : https://github.com/kriskowal/q/issues/188 between the OP and the package maintainer provides a detailed explanation and solution.

In summary, listeners must be registered via a call to `.progress` before the promiser makes calls to `.notify`. This means examples where the promiser is calling notify synchronously will likely occur before the `.progress` listener is registered, and thus the example will appear broken. The addTimeout solution provided by @bennedich satisfies this requirement.

This ordering requirement is not consistent with the experience of a listener registered via a call to `.then` *after* the promiser calls `.resolve`. In this scenario the listener is still called despite the ordering. But for that listener to be called after, the Q package has to perform *magic* (see the guy in the wizard hat : https://github.com/kriskowal). The same magic is deliberately NOT provided for listeners to `.progress` thus the ordering requirement mentioned in this and previous answers.

HTH